# onChange not firing for custom Child component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, components, lifting

I have a custom built component called `Autocomplete` that is essentially a text input box, that among other things, gets the user input when its is typed in. It has an `onChange` handler like this:

```
class Autocomplete extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            activeSuggestion: 0,
            filteredSuggestions: [],
            showSuggestions: false,
            userInput: ""
        };
    }

    //Lifted function to reset autocomplete for Reset button
    handleReset = () => {
        this.setState({
            userInput: ""
        });
    };

    //Begin Autocomplete functionality
    onChange = e => {
        const { suggestions } = this.props;
        const userInput = e.currentTarget.value;
        const filteredSuggestions = suggestions.filter(
            suggestion =>
                suggestion.toLowerCase().indexOf(userInput.toLowerCase()) > -1
        );
        this.setState({
            activeSuggestion: 0,
            filteredSuggestions,
            showSuggestions: true,
            userInput: e.currentTarget.value
        });
    };
     ....
```

I use this component in a parent form component like this:

```
<Autocomplete ref={autoCompleteRef} suggestions={affiliationData}
    onChange={myChangeHandler}/>
```

I am trying to lift the value of the userInput to my hook. I initially tried using `useRef` in myChangeHandler, but I can't get it to fire inside the parent component:

```
function AddContactForm() {
  const [name, setName] = useState();
  const [title, setTitle] = useState();
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState();
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState();
  const [county, setCounty] = useState();
  const [affiliation, setAffiliation] = useState();
  const [centralRegionLead, setCentralRegionLead] = useState("True");

  const myChangeHandler = (event) => {
    let nam = event.target.name;
    let val = event.target.value;
    if (nam === 'name') {
      setName(val);
    } else if (nam === 'title') {
      setTitle(val);
    } else if (nam === 'current') {
      setCurrent(val);
    } else if (nam === 'email') {
      setEmail(val);
    } else if (nam === 'phone') {
      setPhone(val);
    } else if (nam === 'county') {
      setCounty(val);
    } else if (nam === 'autocomplete') {
      const { state } = autoCompleteRef.current;
      setAffiliation(state.userInput);
    } else if (nam === 'centralRegionLead') {
      setCentralRegionLead(val);
    }
  }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand correctly -- it looks like you're managing the state of the userInput in the child Autocomplete component, and to access userInput in the parent component, you'll have to declare and manage the userInput state in the parent component and pass it to Autocomplete as a prop.

Apologies if I misunderstood...

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow. I do have a hook in the parent component called `Affiliation`. The Autocomplete is used for the `Affiliation' userInput that comes from the child component, `Autocomplete`. I can access the value in the parent component with `useRef` but I can't figure out how to pass it to the `Affiliations` hook whenever the `userInput` value changes. Can you provide some example as to how I would do what you propose?

Comment: Sorry, couldn't comment due to reputation so had to put an answer -- I'm confused about the structure. Which component is the parent and which are the children? Separately, it looks like you're passing myChangeHandler as a prop to Autocomplete with: `<Autocomplete onChange={myChangeHandler} ... />` but youre also declaring a new onChange function within the autocomplete class. when a change occurs, do you want both functions to run? If so, there doesn't seem to be a call to the prop.onChange within the autocomplete component